# Explain this duplicate line removing, order retaining, one-line AWK command

Tags: unix, command-line, awk

I learned a really handy way to remove duplicate lines retaining the order from *[Remove duplicates without sorting file - BASH](http://www.unixcl.com/2008/03/remove-duplicates-without-sorting-file.html)*.

Say, if you have the following file,

```
$cat file
a
a
b
b
a
c
```

you can use the following to remove the duplicate lines:

```
$awk '!x[$1]++' file
a
b
c
```

How does this work in terms of precedence of operations?

Comment: I don't understand the question? It removes duplicate lines. What precedence do you mean?

Comment: Just a note: it will  remove not only the duplicated lines but _all lines with the same value at the first column_, too! Add a line with `d a` and `d b` to the file and you will see what I mean. To remove only duplicated lines, you can write `!x[$0]++`, since `$0` returns all the line, not only the first column. To understand it better, see @larsmans answer.

Comment: @Oliver: Operator precedence.

Comment: @brandizzi sorry for the delay! I usually wait 3~5days to select the best answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The expression is parsed as

```
!(x[$(1)]++)
```

So, from the inside out, it's:

- Take field 1 of the current input line, `$(1)` (note that `$` is an operator in AWK, unlike in Perl).
- Index `x` with the value of field 1; if `x` is an unbound variable, bind it to a new associative array.
- Post-increment `x[$(1)]`; a rule similar to the one in C applies, so the value of the expression is that of `x[$(1)]` prior to the increment, which will be zero if `x[$(1)]` has not yet been assigned a value.
- Negate the value of the previous, which will yield truth when `x[$(1)]` is zero.
- Actually do the increment so that `x[$(1)]` gets a non-zero value. So, the next time, `x[$(1)]` for the same value of `$(1)` will return 1.

This expression is then evaluated for every line in the input and determines whether the implied default action of `awk` should be executed, which is to echo the line to `stdout`.

Comment: Just a complement: `!x[$1]++` is an expression which, if true, will execute the following block of code. However, it does not have any block of code; in this case, the default behavior is to execute the `print` command, which prints the current line if no parameter is given to it. This means that, in this case, `!x[$1]++` is equivalent to `!x[$1]++{print;}`. So, the first line a value is returned by `$(1)`, the result of `!x[$1]++` will be true and the line will be printed out; the next times, however, `!x[$1]++` will yield false, and the lines will not be printed.

Answer (score 0):

In AWK arrays are associative, so the first column or first field of each line, `$1`, is used as an index for the array `x`.