# awk filter out messages/rules and display number of merged messages

Tags: shell, awk, filter, line, rules

For the company that I work for, I want to filter out certain messages in a (actually:2) logfile.

These messages are just informative and is not particularly useful when troubleshoot for errors/faults.

After long delibiration (I also posted a similar question, but for Windows and it's PS/BS (certain kind of "cow dung" ;) )

I think AWK is suitable for the job, and I have a shell script made.
However, it isn't running (expected).
Can somebody help me "filling in the blanks"?

```
#!/bin/bash

## URL that could have been the answer (but not quite)    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842118/explain-this-duplicate-line-removing-order-retaining-one-line-awk-command



###To sort by what you WANT to see:
##e.g awk '/term to search/' dpkg.log

#if 
#    $var_show awk '/installed/' syslog/dpkg.log
#    then
#    printf('$var_show')
#fi







##Show what DONT want to see.
if
    #$var_notshow awk /'what not to display'/ syslog/dpkg.log
    $var_notshow awk /'Status Installed'/ dpkg.log
then
wc -1 > $var_notshow 
#echo number of merged messages (of the same content): xxx merged messages #< is the amount 
echo Messages of Status installed: $var_notshow were merged
fi 
###!!Show the amount of rules (when the same rule/logged event) that were merged
## E.g. (multiple lines which state: "Status Installed: xxxxxxxxxxxxx" ) and display it as: "Messages of Status Installed: xxxx were merged. Totalling: # of messages (of Status Installed)" were merged. 

### Finally, save it in a different file.
#Like: ?? how to do that?
```

So, basically I got two ways of doing this: filter what you want or what you don't want. It might be nicer/cleaner to start filtering out messages I don't want.

And yes, as a proof of concept, I used a standard logfile in my testmachine.
I can convert it to the company specific information...

Excerpt from log file:

```
 11:56:31 status half-configured grep:amd64 3.1-2
 11:56:32 status installed grep:amd64 3.1-2
 11:56:32 configure debconf:all 1.5.66 <none>
 11:56:32 status unpacked debconf:all 1.5.66
 11:56:32 status unpacked debconf:all 1.5.66
 11:56:32 status unpacked debconf:all 1.5.66
 11:56:32 status half-configured debconf:all 1.5.66
 11:56:32 status installed debconf:all 1.5.66
 11:56:32 configure gzip:amd64 1.6-5ubuntu1 <none>
 11:56:33 status half-configured util-linux:amd64 2.31.1-0.
 11:56:34 status installed util-linux:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3
 11:56:34 configure libpam-modules-bin:amd64 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2 <none>
 11:56:34 status unpacked libpam-modules-bin:amd64 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
 11:56:34 status half-configured libpam-modules-bin:amd64 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
 11:56:34 status installed libpam-modules-bin:amd64 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
 11:56:34 configure mount:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3 <none>
 11:56:34 status unpacked mount:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3
 11:56:34 status half-configured mount:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3
 11:56:34 status installed mount:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3
 11:56:34 configure procps:amd64 2:3.3.12-3ubuntu1 <none>
 11:56:34 status unpacked procps:amd64 2:3.3.12-3ubuntu1
 11:56:34 status unpacked procps:amd64 2:3.3.12-3ubuntu1
 11:56:34 status unpacked procps:amd64 2:3.3.12-3ubuntu1
```

Thanks in advance :)

Thomas

Comment: Sounds like something `awk` could do. Please share some sample data and your desired output from awk, otherwise I'm not sure we can help more than agreeing with your choice of `awk`.

Comment: Glad it can. I have made an small excerpt of the logfile (test-vm's standard dpkg.log). Availble at: https://pastebin.com/bnri9gfa .

And what I want to display from the awkscript:
Found 23 loglines(<this is optional to what I want).  5 messages of 'Status Installed' were merged(awk will take the full line and not just "Status Installed" ). Hope this helps to clarify it

Comment: What do you mean "Awk will take the full line and not just "Status Installed"". With these 23 lines of sample, can you provide exactly what you want awk to spit out and if there is any not obvious logic to get there, share that too. "Take" and "Merge" are what I'm really tripping on here. I have no idea what those two terms mean in regards to awk.

Comment: The other point of confusion is the code you've posted. It's so very far off from working and filled with commented out code and not-commented out code (that definitely doesn't do what you want it to do) that it doesn't help the question. Please explain better what you want as the output here with this sample. There's very few clues to go off of here that are meaningful.

Comment: @ThomasAnoniem Found something useful?

Comment: @steffen.Yes, the grep "interesting" (randomly tried it on recently installed zsh package) works fine. Also tried it writing it to an new file. Like a charm....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show all interesting lines:

```
grep interesting file
```

Show all except uninteresting lines:

```
grep -v "Status uninteresting" file
```

Count with awk:

```
awk '/uninteresting/{n++}END{print "uninteresting messages: "n}'
```

Redirect command output into a new file:

```
grep interesting file | grep -v uninteresting > newFile
```

Or append to newFile:

```
grep interesting file | grep -v uninteresting >> newFile
```

Do everything at once:

```
awk '/uninteresting/{u++;next}/interesting/{print}END{print "uninteresting lines: "u}'
this is interesting
uninteresting lines: 1
```

Comment: Gonna try this when I have the chance. Thanks steffen